# DAX Calculated column with concatenated values from column of filtered table

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have three tables of data, Avaya call records and ServiceNow incident tickets, and ServiceNow interaction tickets (model has a number of other tables, but the only relevant one is an employee info table). I have a calculated column that matches call records to tickets based on matching employee ID, date, and time range.  It yields a count of tickets, which has been sufficient as we were only concerned with identifying employees that were taking calls without cutting any tickets.  We are now trying to look at the average call duration for certain incident types and need to get a list of ticket numbers associated with each call, but I keep getting a blank output.
This is the working dax formula for generating a ticket count:

```
Tickets Associated = 
var agent = RELATED('Team Members'[MMID])
var ondate = FORMAT('Avaya - Full Call Records'[Date],"m/d/yy")
var starttime = 'Avaya - Full Call Records'[Answer Time]
var endtime = 'Avaya - Full Call Records'[Next call start]

var inrangeinc = FILTER('SNow - INC Tickets', FORMAT('SNow - INC Tickets'[Open Date],"m/d/yy")=ondate
                    &&'SNow - INC Tickets'[OpenedBy]=agent
                    &&'SNow - INC Tickets'[OpenTime]<=endtime
                    &&'SNow - INC Tickets'[OpenTime]>=starttime
)
var inrangeims = FILTER('SNow -  IMS InteractionTickets',FORMAT('SNow -  IMS InteractionTickets'[Open Date-Rel],"m/d/yy")=ondate
                    &&'SNow -  IMS InteractionTickets'[OpenedBy]=agent
                    &&'SNow -  IMS InteractionTickets'[OpenTime]<=endtime
                    &&'SNow -  IMS InteractionTickets'[OpenTime]>=starttime
)
var inccount = COUNTROWS(inrangeinc)
var imscount = COUNTROWS(inrangeims)
var ticketcount = imscount+inccount
return 
    if(ISBLANK(ticketcount),0,ticketcount)
```

This is what I have right now that is giving a blank result, I've tried a couple of different variations with the same results.

```
INC Nums Associated = 
var agent = RELATED('Team Members'[MMID])
var ondate = FORMAT('Avaya - Full Call Records'[Date],"m/d/yy")
var starttime = 'Avaya - Full Call Records'[Answer Time]
var endtime = 'Avaya - Full Call Records'[Next call start]

var inrangeinc = SELECTCOLUMNS(
             FILTER('SNow - INC Tickets', 
                        FORMAT('SNow - INC Tickets'[Open Date],"m/d/yy")=ondate
                                &&'SNow - INC Tickets'[OpenedBy]=agent
                                &&'SNow - INC Tickets'[OpenTime]<=endtime
                                &&'SNow - INC Tickets'[OpenTime]>=starttime
                    ),
            "INC Numbers",'SNow - INC Tickets'[TicketNumber]
            )


return 
CONCATENATEX(
    FILTER('SNow - INC Tickets','SNow - INC Tickets'[TicketNumber] IN inrangeinc),
    'SNow - INC Tickets'[TicketNumber],","
    )
```